# what is 1P frequency in rotor (wind turbine)?

Tags: measurements, signal-processing, wind-power

In wind turbine, Is the number of revolution taken in 1s is called 1P frequency? If not, is it possible to find the 1P rpm from rpm measured for 1 hour (that is, I have 60 rpm data points from tachometer)?

Comment: You are mixing up your units.  RPM per hour makes no sense. Do you mean revolutions per hour? Edit required.

Comment: I meant I have measured rpm every minute for an hour. That is, I have 60 rpm data points

Answer (score 2):

The constant rotational speed is the first excitation frequency, mostly referred to as 1P. The second excitation frequency is the rotor blade passing frequency: NbP in which Nb is the number of rotor blades: 2P for a turbine equipped with two rotor blades, 3P for a three bladed rotor.

source: https://ocw.tudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/Soft_soft___Berlijn_2002.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> In wind turbine, is the number of revolution taken in 1 s is called 1P frequency?

According to [Dynamics of offshore wind turbines
supported on two foundations](http://epubs.surrey.ac.uk/790106/1/ICE-GE-Special_Issue_2013.pdf) you are correct.

> If not, is it possible to find the 1P rpm from rpm measured for 1 hour (that is, I have 60 rpm data points from tachometer)?

Average the RPM readings and divide by 60 (seconds in one minute).

Disclaimer: I looked up the first part. I am an EE but never heard of 1P before.